# Django Form foreign key relationship

Tags: django

I'm building a simple application to collection emp infor and emp address.

I have 2 tables.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
      fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      lname = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class EmployeeAdd(models.Model):
      emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
      city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Now, Im planning to create 2 form EmpForm and EmpAddressForm.

Is it possible to display both these form together in one single page and collect both emp and empaddr information?

Comment: If there is a OneToOne relationship between EmpleyeeAd and Employee? Then you could do: class EmployeeAdd(Empolyee) and make a modelform with all fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Django documentation about [Model Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)?  It has a section on [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) that might help you.

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets. These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign key